# RecyclerView not show Items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have problem why RecyclerView not show Items I dont know why not show Items.

json url

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "English",
    "photo": "en.png",
    "shortcut": "en"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Spanish",
    "photo": "es.png",
    "shortcut": "es"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Arabic",
    "photo": "ar.png",
    "shortcut": "ar"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Russian",
    "photo": "ru.png",
    "shortcut": "ru"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Portuguese",
    "photo": "pt.png",
    "shortcut": "pt"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "title": "French",
    "photo": "fr.png",
    "shortcut": "fr"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Turkish",
    "photo": "tr.png",
    "shortcut": "tr"
  }
]
```

activity

```
public class CategoriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //mapping
    @BindView(R.id.rv_categories)
    RecyclerView rv_categories;

    CategoriesAdapter categoriesAdapter;
    List<CategoriesModel> categoriesModels = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
        ButterKnife.bind(CategoriesActivity.this);
        //set data
        setData();
    }

    private void setData() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("***Stackoverflow")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RetrofitService retrofitService = retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
        Call<List<CategoriesModel>> call = retrofitService.get_categories();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CategoriesModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CategoriesModel>> call, Response<List<CategoriesModel>> response) {
                List<CategoriesModel> list = response.body();
                for (CategoriesModel data : list) {
                    categoriesModels.add(new CategoriesModel(data.id, data.title, data.photo, data.shortcut));
                }
                rv_categories.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(CategoriesActivity.this, 2));
                categoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(CategoriesActivity.this, categoriesModels);
                rv_categories.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CategoriesModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Model

```
public class CategoriesModel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
    @SerializedName("photo")
    public String photo;
    @SerializedName("shortcut")
    public String shortcut;

    public CategoriesModel(String id, String title, String photo, String shortcut) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.shortcut = shortcut;
    }
}
```

interface

```
public interface RetrofitService {

    //Categories
    @GET("Categories/get_categories.php")
    Call<List<CategoriesModel>> get_categories();

}
```

Adapter

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<CategoriesModel> categoriesModels;

    public CategoriesAdapter(Context context, List<CategoriesModel> categoriesModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoriesModels = categoriesModels;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_categories, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder adapterHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return adapterHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        CategoriesModel categoriesModel = categoriesModels.get(i);
        //set photo
        Picasso.get().load(viewHolder.url + categoriesModel.photo).into(viewHolder.img_background);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoriesModels.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //mapping
        @BindView(R.id.img_background)
        ImageView img_background;
        @BindString(R.string.categories)
        String url;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(context, view);
        }

    }

}
```

row_categories

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

</ImageView>
```

activity_categories.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CategoriesActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since yesterday I was trying to figure out where the problem was and I did not find the problem ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, I hope help me thank you so mush

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow! What response do you get from server? Are you sure the data is fetched successfully?

Comment: List<CategoriesModel> list = response.body(); I think problem is there.

Comment: guys I can print data via Toast but not showing in List :(

Comment: Do the RecyclkerView have space on screen? add a backkground color to it and see it on layout

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I have ImageView I edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid this code

```
for (CategoriesModel data : list) {
      categoriesModels.add(new CategoriesModel(data.id, data.title, data.photo, data.shortcut));
}
```

And do something like `categoriesModels.addAll(list);`

In your `ViewHolder` you do not need this

```
@BindString(R.string.categories)
String url;
```

Since your `R.layout.row_categories` only contains a `ImageView`.

Try to change your `row_categories.xml` to this one :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also your `RecyclerView` try to change the height to `wrap_content`

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_categories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

If didn't work, try to change your `onCreate()` to this one :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_categories);
    ButterKnife.bind(CategoriesActivity.this);
    rv_categories.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv_categories.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(CategoriesActivity.this, 2));
    setData();
}
```

### EDIT

I think the problem is here

```
public class CategoriesModel {

    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    public String title;
    @SerializedName("photo")
    public String photo;
    @SerializedName("shortcut")
    public String shortcut;

    public CategoriesModel(String id, String title, String photo, String shortcut) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.shortcut = shortcut;
    }
}
```

And the problem is here

```
Picasso.get().load(viewHolder.url + categoriesModel.photo).into(viewHolder.img_background);
```

You have to change it to

```
Picasso.get().load(URL_BASE+"Forvo/Categories/Images/" + categoriesModel.getPhoto()).into(viewHolder.img_background);
```

You have to add the `Setter` and `Getter` for all of those attributes.

I recommend you to use [JsonSchema2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) whenever you want to parse a POJO class.

Comment: I tried print Toast in onBindViewHolder but there is no any message

Comment: Did you try to print for instance categoriesModel.getSomething()?

Comment: did you want I give you url JSON for check in your computer ?

Comment: No, follow my steps and it will work, follow the steps from the edit if it doesn't work, I'll try to do it by myself

Comment: in fact It's dont working It's first time to use retrofit , my url

http://salah-android.com/Forvo/Categories/get_categories.php

thanks a lot for your time <3

Comment: Ok, let me check

Comment: and Image url , 
http://salah-android.com/Forvo/Categories/Images/en.png

Comment: Ok, do this : on your MainActivity create this public static final URL_BASE = "http://salah-android.com/"; then in your retrofit put .baseURL(URL_BASE), then change your RetrofitService to this : @GET("Forvo/Categories/get_categories.php"), then add the Setter and getter in your CategoriesModel class and change the Picaso code that is on my answer and it will work.

Comment: It's working thank you a lot :D , thanks for your time best answer

Comment: done I makred your answer :D but you can change url to *** ?

Comment: No, why you would do this?

Comment: There's lot of options on StackOverflow :P search it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure predefine your image view size. Because loaded image is sized up to it unless you declare something else.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp">

   <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img_background"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_margin="5dp">
</ImageView>
```

And pick a another image url from google or something else which only shows image when you go for link to be sure if your url parameters are wrong.